# How do you make an object inactive in Lua (using Corona SDK) after collision?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I am writing in Lua, using the Corona SDK, and  I am looking to make an object inactive after a collision.

```
function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        bullet.collided = true
        bullet.isVisible = false
        bullet:applyLinearImpulse(-5, 0, bullet.x, bullet.y)
        explode(event)
    end 
end 

function explode(event)
    local x = event.object2.x
    local y = event.object2.y

    explosion.x = x
    explosion.y = y
    explosion.isVisible = true
    explosion:play()
    resetExplosion()
end
```

The above function takes the single bullet on the screen and makes it invisible after a collision with a ball that it shoots in the y axis. It then applys an impulse to remove it from the screen in the x-axis. My issue is that the ball (object2) in the collision is invisible after collision as well, but it still can be hit by the new bullet. There is only one bullet, so I can directly say bullet.whatever, but there is an array of balls, so the ball has to be addressed like ball[i].whatever. 
is there a way to pass the index, i through the onCollision function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the body to inactive if you use a slight delay in your collision handler.
i.e:

```
-- Inside your Collision event
local function delay()
    --Change the body's active state to false
    body.isBodyActive = false
end

timer.performWithDelay( 10, delay )
```

Comment: That worked! I added that code and then re-activated the body when it resets. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [CoronaSDK chapter about event.collision](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/collision/index.html) `event.object1` and `event.object2` are the properties identifying those collided objects (**references** to the bullet and one of the balls in Your case). So, doesn't it solve Your problem?

Comment: Well, event.object1 or event.object2 are useful but they have limitations. For instance, I can (and do) make the event.object2:isVisible = false; however, I can't reset object2's x position, or move it in another direction or something like that.